# Clip a grid to a shapefile but keep cells whole

Tags: r, gis, shapefile, r-sf

I have two shapefiles: One Hexagonal Grid, One Bounding Shapefile:

[image: Grid & Bounding Shapefile]

I am trying to clip the Grid to the Shapefile BUT no matter how I try
`st_intersect()`, `st_overlap()`, `st_contains()`, etc, the result is always the same:

[image: Undesired Clipping Output]

What I want is to clip the Grid and keep the remaining cells whole like this:

[image: Desired Clipping Output]

I *can* accomplish this in QGIS, but I am looking for a solution in R.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code to replicate the grid and the bounding shapefile? Also could you share the code used to generate the plot with the gray hexagons? I think `st_overlaps` should be able to perform the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```r
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)


# example data
# using the state border of north carolina
nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%
  st_union()

# create a bounding box
bbox <- st_bbox(nc) %>% st_as_sfc()

# make a hexagonal grid over the bounding box
hex_grid <- st_make_grid(bbox, square = FALSE, n = 40)  
hex_sf <- hex_grid %>% st_as_sf()

#index of hexagons fully or partially covered by the state
intersections_index <- st_intersects(nc, hex_grid, sparse = F)

# sf object of only the hexagons we want
intersected_hex <- hex_sf[intersections_index, ]

## plotting it all:
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = hex_sf, color = 'orange') +
  geom_sf(data = intersected_hex, fill = 'gray40')+
  geom_sf(data = nc, color = 'blue', fill = NA)
```

Full hexagonal grid in orange, selected hexagons in gray, state outline (bounding shapefile) in blue.
[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>